# Предлагаю объединить метки [swiper] и [swiper.js]

Tags: предложение, метки, правки

Метка [swiper](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper) - 210 вопросов, нет описания.

Метка [swiper.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper.js) - 4 вопроса, есть описание.

Может метка `[swiper]` еще для чего-то нужна, но 99% вопросов, более чем уверен, связаны с библиотекой swiper.js.

Comment: Можно посмотреть [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper+-javascript), в которых есть swiper, но нет js. Чтобы определиться с объединением.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ они все про swiper.js, в этом и беда

Comment: @αλεχολυτ спасибо за правку, не знал про tag)